# Access bad error in static library

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

I am getting an error of Access bad. I have checked it,this is due to release an object in the static library. I checked that header file in the library the object is of assign type which is releasing. Can i do any thing without change in static library. i have only header files of library classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retain that object before pass it to the library. And then release it later at some point you think of.

Comment: I am not passing it to library it is in the internal business logic of library. I have a function with parameter to call in library.